# Options for replacing SOAP toolkit in Excel 2003 for upgrade to Excel 2010 to access Web Services

Tags: excel, service, web

We currently access some web services in Excel 2003 using SOAP Toolkit which works fine.

However we are gradually moving on to Excel 2010 and I have been asked to look into options to  access Web Services in Excel 2010.

I can obviously use Visual studio and the Excel workbook add-in, which I am currently researching and seems to be the obvious candidate but I am wondering which other options might be available to me to look into ?

Cheers, George.

Answer (score 0):

I used VSTO which worked fine.